# How do I create a bash script that can extract strings from an array?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a dilemma, I'm trying to write a Linux bash script so that it would extract each string from an array, and process the result.

IE

```
var=("string one" "string two" "string three")
```

How would I use a for loop to extract each string, baring in mind the strings have spaces, so I would need to extract the entire string, ie "string three", then within that fo loop, it would process the result.

EG

```
#! /bin/bash

clear
SimName=("Welcome" "Testing Region")
echo
echo
echo
echo
#cd dreamgrid/Opensim/bin

# for loop goes here

# processing below
#screen -S "$SimName" -d -m mono OpenSim.exe -inidirectory="Regions/$SimName"  # Needs altering to process each string
#sleep 2
#screen -r "$SimName"   # Needs chaging to show each string in turn.

# echo $SimName[1]   # something test to it with, but needs changing to show each string in turn.
```

In BASIC it's simple:

```
DIM A$(2)
A$(1) = "string one"
A$(2) = "string two"
FOR A=1 to 2
C$=A$(A)
FOR DL=1 TO 2000
NEXT
PRINT C$
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
for val in "${arr[@]}"; do 
  # something with "$val"
done
```

ex.

```
$ arr=("string one" "string two" "string three")
$ for val in "${arr[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$val"; done
string one
string two
string three
```

The double quoting of `"${arr[@]}"` is what makes it correctly handle elements containing whitespace (or, more generally, characters from the current `IFS`). From `man bash`:

> ```
>                                                                        If
>    the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the
>    value of each array member separated by the first character of the  IFS
>    special variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a sep‐
>    arate word.
> ```